# eth0 missing after upgrading from Hoary to Dapper

Tags: networking

I'm trying to upgrade a fairly old server that's been running Hoary for the last five years. I followed the directions [on the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades), but when I restarted after upgrading to Dapper, eth0 disappeared from `ifconfig -a`. I can see two ethernet adapters in `lspci` and `lshw`, and if I put in an Ubuntu 10.10 LiveCD it registers eth0 and eth1 perfectly well. Their MAC addresses also match what's in /etc/iftab.

It was working fine before the upgrade, and I have no idea what else I should be trying at this point. The server is entirely cut off from the network right now.

EDIT: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` doesn't exist, either.

Comment: I was going to try installing the e1000 driver, since it seems to be missing, but the server isn't recognizing my USB thumb drive, and my LiveCD freezes before I can copy the driver over that way. Apparently I have more problems than just eth0, so I'm going to begin migrating to a new server. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You are kidding, right?  Hoary's support ended in late 2006.  You didn't notice it kept complaining that it could not get updates when they closed the repository for it almost 5 years ago?  You can't directly upgrade from Hoary to Dapper ( skipping Breezy ), which hasn't been supported on the desktop since late 2009.

If you are serious and not just trolling, then you need to do a clean install of a supported release ( 10.04+ ), and keep up to date.  That means upgrading every 6 month release, or sticking with 10.04 until it is time to upgrade to the next LTS in 12.04.

Comment: Excuse me, I linked to the Wiki page where it shows how to upgrade from an end-of-life'd version. I went from Hoary through Breezy to Dapper, which is where I restarted. I can't see how I'd be trolling.

Comment: Also, please don't assume I've been maintaining this server the whole time. I have not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules. I think you need to reboot afterwards.

Comment: That file doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh... Hoary is so terribly old. I would install 10.04 from scratch if at all possible.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'll do that if that's my last option, but I'm hoping it'll be easier to fix this than to migrate everything.